# Value of the variable is assigned only on the second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

My method do a `.map()` in `array` with `props` and assign to variable. I call my method with a `button`, `console` it, but your value is empty.

Only when I call for the second time my `console.log` returns a first value.

I'm using React and my `array` comes from `props`. This is my code:

```
  myFunction = () => {  
    let a = this.props.myArray.map(foo => (foo.content))
    console.log(a);    
  }
```

And I call `myFunction` here:

```
<button onClick={this.myFunction }>Get!</button>
```

In short, I click in the button and my `a` variable in `console` is empty. I click again in my button and finally my variable have a value.

Why does this happen? What do I need do to get a value in the first interaction, in the first click in my button?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to be able to help you, sadly. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: @HemadriDasari wrapping your function is not needed and does not yield any other result. Wrapping is only needed when you want to pass in a (dynamic) value to that function.

Comment: Or even better, use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to show the code here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution

```
  myFunction = () => {  
    let a = this.props.myArray.map(foo => foo.content)
    console.log(a);    
  }
```

Here is sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wznkoql5n)